# Apple GLPaint modification problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, opengl-es, paint

I followed Apple's **GLPaint** paint application and tried to modify it.. In sample code they have used simple **particle.png** to draw.

[image: Before modification]

**My question is i want to use some other image of my choice for drawing.** At first sight it seems very easy to replace **"particle.png"** with some **"finger.png"** but it did not work.. When I replaced **"particle.png"** with **"finger.png"** , I got something like this :

[image: After replacing particle.png]

My **"finger.png"** image looks somthing like this :

[image]

Link :  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Listings/Classes_PaintingView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328-Classes_PaintingView_m-DontLinkElementID_6

Partial Code:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder 
{

CGSize          myShadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0,  0);


 NSMutableArray*     recordedPaths;
 CGImageRef          brushImage;
 CGContextRef     brushContext;
 GLubyte               *brushData;
 size_t               width, height;


      // Create a texture from an image
      // First create a UIImage object from the data in a image file, and then extract the Core Graphics image

   ////--------------------Modification--------------------------------///////    

        brushImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"finger.png"].CGImage;  


  ////--------------------Modification--------------------------------///////     



     // Get the width and height of the image
      width = CGImageGetWidth(brushImage);
      height = CGImageGetHeight(brushImage);
      NSLog(@"%f%f",(CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height);
      // Texture dimensions must be a power of 2. If you write an application that allows users to supply an image,
      // you'll want to add code that checks the dimensions and takes appropriate action if they are not a power of 2.

      // Make sure the image exists
      if(brushImage) 
    {
           // Allocate  memory needed for the bitmap context
           brushData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
           // Use  the bitmatp creation function provided by the Core Graphics framework. 
           brushContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(brushData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(brushImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
           // After you create the context, you can draw the  image to the context.
           CGContextDrawImage(brushContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), brushImage);
           // You don't need the context at this point, so you need to release it to avoid memory leaks.

        CGContextRelease(brushContext);
           // Use OpenGL ES to generate a name for the texture.
           glGenTextures(1, &brushTexture);
           // Bind the texture name. 
           glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTexture);
           // Set the texture parameters to use a minifying filter and a linear filer (weighted average)
           glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
           // Specify a 2D texture image, providing the a pointer to the image data in memory
           glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, brushData);
           // Release  the image data; it's no longer needed
        free(brushData);
  }
```

I do not understand why I am getting drawing like this. Can anyone point me out that  what other changes I need to make to make this application work as before?? I am not expert at OpenGL so any help or suggestion will be appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you have to make the image white on transparent in order for it to work.  If you have blue with transparency around it, it will show the entire picture as opaque.

I took the standard Apple GLPaint app.  I replaced particle.png with a finger.png that I made in Photoshop.  It is 64x64 RGB 8 bits.  The entire image is transparent except for a white smudge which I copied directly from your blue finger.png.  Here is the output in the simulator:
[image]

Comment: @cdshader : Thanks for suggestion..Maybe you are correct but let me be more specific. When I used **finger.png** I got those square images**(marked with red ellipse)** on touch/tap.. So is it due to that transparency you were talking about?

Comment: I believe so, You are seeing the entire rect that is the image.  I would imagine that your finger.png is a square image the same size as your solid squares.

Comment: So if you resize your finger.png to say 200x200 pixels in a graphics program and save it, does the square get bigger? or stay the same?  I have swapped out the brush in Apple's GLPaint app and didn't have any issues ...

Comment: I just made a new finger.png that is white on transparent in photoshop and replaced particle.png with finger.png in the Apple GLPaint example and it works.  Try making the finger.png white on transparent RGB 8 bits and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but I find if you change #define kBrushScale in PaintingView.h, you get interesting effects. Try changing to .25, .5. .75 1.0 etc...

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But that project got terminated unfortunately.. So I do not remember correctly what I did that time. But I will surely try to look into it in a short time.. :-)